# How can i expand internal list to new rows in polars DataFrame (reversed aggregation)

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a `pl.DataFrame` with nested `lists`.
I'd like to translate every row to have single value of list in it.

Example snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl


def expand(df):
    # do the job
    return df


df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": ["A", "B"],
        "y": [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
    }
)
expected_df = pl.DataFrame({"x": ["A", "A", "B", "B"], "y": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

assert expand(df).frame_equal(expected_df)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`.explode()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html#polars.DataFrame.explode)

```
df.explode('y')
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ A   ┆ 1   │
│ A   ┆ 2   │
│ B   ┆ 3   │
│ B   ┆ 4   │
└─────┴─────┘
```